# How to add new activities to an existing brightway2 database?

Tags: brightway

I loaded the ecoinvent database as shown below. I would like to calculate the impact of a created activity that takes in cotton fibre and polyester fibre as input and produces a mixed fibre as output. How do I do it?

```
eidb = bw.Database('ecoinvent_3_8_cutoff')

db_name = "ecoinvent_3_8_cutoff"
# activity to be created and impact found

   {(db_name, "test_product"): {
        'activity': 'test_process_00001',
        'activity type': 'aggregated market activty',
        'code': 'Not available',
        'location': 'GLO',
        'name':'test activity',
        'parameters': [],
        'production amount': 1.0,
        'reference product': 'test_product',
        'exchanges': [{
            'input': (db_name, 'market for fibre, cotton'),
            'amount': 0.5,
            'type': 'technosphere'
        }, {
            'input': (db_name, 'market for fibre, polyester'),
            'amount': 0.5,
            'type': 'technosphere'            
        }, {
            'output': (db_name, 'mixed fibre'),
            'amount': 1,
            'type': 'technosphere'
        }]
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a new `Database`:

```py
db_name = "ecoinvent_3_8_cutoff"
bw2data.Database("another db").write(
    [{
        ("another db", "test_product"): {
            'activity': 'test_process_00001',
            'activity type': 'aggregated market activty',
            'code': 'Not available',
            'location': 'GLO',
            'name':'test activity',
            'parameters': [],
            'production amount': 1.0,
            'reference product': 'test_product',
            'exchanges': [{
                'input': (db_name, 'market for fibre, cotton'),
                'amount': 0.5,
                'type': 'technosphere'
            }, {
                'input': (db_name, 'market for fibre, polyester'),
                'amount': 0.5,
                'type': 'technosphere'            
            }, {
                'output': (db_name, 'mixed fibre'),
                'amount': 1,
                'type': 'technosphere'
            }]
        }
    }]
)
```

In the same `Database`:

```py
db_name = "ecoinvent_3_8_cutoff"
db = bw2data.Database(db_name)
act = db.new_activity(
    **{
        'activity': 'test_process_00001',
        'activity type': 'aggregated market activty',
        'code': 'Not available',
        'location': 'GLO',
        'name':'test activity',
        'production amount': 1.0,
        'reference product': 'test_product',
    }
)
act.save()
act.new_exchange(
    input=(db_name, 'market for fibre, cotton'),
    amount= 0.5,
    type= 'technosphere'
).save()
act.new_exchange(**{
    'input': (db_name, 'market for fibre, polyester'),
    'amount': 0.5,
    'type': 'technosphere'                       
}).save()
act.new_exchange(**{
    'output': (db_name, 'mixed fibre'),
    'amount': 1,
    'type': 'technosphere'
})
```

These examples use [`**` to expand keyword arguments](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/). You don't have to.

Note that `('ecoinvent_3_8_cutoff', 'mixed fibre')` are not valid ecoinvent activity keys, unless you manually changed them.

Comment: Thank you.
As a follow up, how do we add a new entry/key for 'mixed fibre'? Let's say I want to do an LCA for this new 'mixed fibre' based on the two technosphere exchanges above, how do I go about it? I am assuming the total impact of this new 'mixed fibre' is half 'cotton fibre' and half 'polyester fibre' impact?

Comment: You can use the `act` variable, or, better, get its key and then use that in the future. So, either:
`LCA({act: 1}), some_lcia_method)`
or:
`print(act.key)
LCA({the_key_i_printed: 1}), some_lcia_method)`